# Best practice to modify value/struct

Tags: go

I found that to modify a value/struct I can do it in two ways(maybe others exist).

1. Pass value by reference
2. Get value from function/method, handle error then assign

I know both methods work but I am wondering which method is best practice in the golang world.

I am giving both examples here.

**abc.go**

```
package main

import (
    "fmt"
    "github.com/pkg/errors"
)

type Request struct {
    AdType string
}

type Response struct {
    Message string
}

func main() {
    // Implementation 1
    // Handle response by handle and alter response
    res1 := Response{}
    req1 := Request{AdType: "banner"}
    req1.handleResponse(&res1)

    // Implementation 2
    res2 := Response{}
    req2 := Request{AdType: "image"}
    if r, e := req2.getRequestMessage(); e == nil {
        res2.Message = r
    }
    fmt.Println(res1)
    fmt.Println(res2)
}

func (req *Request) handleResponse(res *Response) {
    if req.AdType == "banner" {
        res.Message = "Banner Ad"
    } else if req.AdType == "video"{
        res.Message = "Video Ad"
    }
}

func (req *Request) getRequestMessage() (string, error) {
    if req.AdType == "banner" {
        return "Banner Ad", nil
    } else if req.AdType == "video"{
        return "Video Ad", nil
    }
    return "", errors.New("Invalid ad type")
}
```

Comment: Use whatever suits you better.

Comment: "Pass value by reference" you cannot do this. There are no references in Go. All you can do pass a pointer by value.

Answer (score 1):

Honestly, I think something like this is more of the standard in go. It's a lot cleaner and easier to follow.

```
package main

import (
    "errors"
    "fmt"
)

type Request struct {
    AdType string
}

type Response struct {
    Message string
}

func main() {
    res, err := handleRequest(&Request{AdType: "banner"})
    if err != nil {
        fmt.Println("error getting response")
    }
    fmt.Println(res)
}

func handleRequest(request *Request) (*Response, error) {
    res := new(Response)
    switch request.AdType {
    case "banner":
        res.Message = "Banner Ad"
        return res, nil
    case "video":
        res.Message = "Video Ad"
        return res, nil
    }
    return nil, errors.New("invalid ad type")
}
```